# My Windows CE cab installer is installing to host c: drive rather than the device

Tags: visual-studio-2008, installation, cab

I have a Win CE application for hand scanners, and I have made an automated installer for it so that users will be able to run a program from their PC to automatically install it to their devices without having to use wither ActiveSync or Windows Mobile Device Center. I have put together a document of instructions (which I will try to attach to a comment) and followed them carefully - but when I run the resulting setup program, it only installs on my c: drive, and doesn't do anything at all to the scanner. Please advise.
My PC has Windows 7, Windows Mobile Device Center, and the scanner is running Windows CE 5.00.

Comment: Apparently there is no way to attach files in StackOverflow, so I have published the instructions I wrote for myself at https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1jBRIayHDTa-C6k7_OiW8-_EAI9_pT165yPnDhQWv1Qg

Comment: Some more information: I have added code to write to a file in the **CustomInstaller** project **InstallerClass.cs** program. What I have discovered is that InstallerClass **InitializeComponent** code section is running, but the **public override void Commit(System.Collections.IDictionary savedState)** code section isn't. Does this help anyone come up with any ideas what might be wrong, please?

Comment: Instructions link changed - for new link [click here](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1scM3LNS3KcPalZzM75SeqUToo_d0NGWYdAvysmjvuZ0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the CAB .inf file and the custom installer ini files, both text files, were written using the Visual Studio 2008 text editor - and neither had ANSI encoding.

An approach I found to be very helpful was to work out how to install manually from the command prompt so that I could find out what my project was supposed to be doing. For example:

C:\Windows\WindowsMobile\CEAppMgr.exe c:\Progra~2\Microsoft\CEScanAppSetup\CustomInstaller.ini